unable to send documents using pipe out connector in streamserve
I am facing issues with pipe outconnector in OpenText Streamserve.
pipe output connector means, output connector with connector type "Pipe", using custom driver and also a queue.
problem:
I am sending documents to print from streamserve to external printer using pipe output connector, if i am invoking the pipe output connector once in a single run(configured to send one file in a single run) there were no issues and everything is running smoothly.
If I am invoking the same connector twice in a single run(configured to send two file in a single run) i am getting this error.
Pipe outconnector: Write to pipe lp -d PRINTER2 failed. (32:Broken pipe)
Tried solutions:

adding delay(sleep) between these two invoke requests(from 20seconds upto 5 minutes delay)
increasing no of retries

Expecting resolve this error
